# GFF file too big to load into R

Tags: r, bioconductor, sequence-annotation, errors

I want to load a GFF (annotation) file into an R data frame in order to extract some information from it, e.g. the location of transposons in the genome.

I used the following code:

```
library(rtracklayer)
gff <- rtracklayer::import('c_elegans.PRJNA13758.WS263.annotations.gff3.gz')
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 210.2 Mb
```

It seems that the GFF3 file is too big for loading into R. Do you know if this is limited by R or by my computer's memory?

I ran this on a GNU/Linux computer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends of course on your available RAM on your computer.

Under Windows you can increase the available RAM in R with memory limit:

```
> memory.limit()
[1] 8070
> memory.limit(size=10000)
[1] 10000
> memory.limit()
[1] 10000
```

But that is not necessary on linux/unix.

Comment: **This only works** (and is only required) **on Windows.** OP is using Linux. Not sure why he accepted this answer.

Comment: Indeed, memory.limit()
[1] Inf
Warning message:
'memory.limit()' is Windows-specific. I understood this as 'no memory limit' on Linux, so only limited by available RAM?